# Apache Solr suggester dictionary is not updated after removing some records from collection

Tags: json, solr

I want to update Solr suggester dictionary after uploading some initial data (in Solr 5.3.1). The suggester dictionary is updated after deleting all data and uploading the modified data back. But when I delete any particular record (eg. id=123), the suggester still returns the deleted record in result set.

For example,

1. I upload following json data initially to mycollection:

json_data.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "New York"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "New Jersey"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "California"
    }
]
```

with this command:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/update?commit=true' --data-binary @json_data.json
```

2. Select query returns the following:

localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0,
        "params": {
            "q": "*:*",
            "indent": "true",
            "wt": "json",
            "_": "1448271522315"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 3,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": [
                    "New York"
                ],
                "_version_": 1518622755181822000
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": [
                    "New Jersey"
                ],
                "_version_": 1518622755186016300
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": [
                    "California"
                ],
                "_version_": 1518622755187064800
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

3. Suggester returns the following for "New" word:

localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/suggest?q=New&wt=json&indent=true

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0
    },
    "spellcheck": {
        "suggestions": [
            "New",
            {
                "numFound": 2,
                "startOffset": 0,
                "endOffset": 3,
                "suggestion": [
                    "New Jersey",
                    "New York"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "collations": [
            "collation",
            "(New Jersey)"
        ]
    }
}
```

4. Now I delete "New Jersey" from mycollection with following command:
   curl http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '(id:2)'
5. Now select query returns only the remaining 2 records (removed "New Jersey")

localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0,
        "params": {
            "q": "*:*",
            "indent": "true",
            "wt": "json",
            "_": "1448272061874"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 2,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": [
                    "New York"
                ],
                "_version_": 1518622755181822000
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": [
                    "California"
                ],
                "_version_": 1518622755187064800
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

6. But the suggest query still returns the "New Jersey" in the resultset

localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/suggest?q=New&wt=json&indent=true

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0
    },
    "spellcheck": {
        "suggestions": [
            "New",
            {
                "numFound": 2,
                "startOffset": 0,
                "endOffset": 3,
                "suggestion": [
                    "New Jersey",
                    "New York"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "collations": [
            "collation",
            "(New Jersey)"
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried after reloading the admin core and restarting the solr server but the result remains unchanged.

What could be the issue? Is there any cache used by suggester component (solr.SpellCheckComponent)? If yes, how can it be cleared?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the spell-checkers and suggesters do not work directly off the index but build a parallel structure. There is a setting that builds on every commit and - if that setting is false - there is a flag you can pass in the request to trigger the rebuild. For spellchecker, this flag is [spellcheck.build or spellcheck.reload](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spell+Checking#SpellChecking-Thespellcheck.buildParameter).

So, check what your configuration has and try calling rebuild/reload explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre for your response. My solrconfig.xml has <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str> setting. I tried both the flags spellcheck.build and spellcheck.reload in suggest request. But none of them updates the suggester dictionary in mycollection. I always get the deleted record "New Jersey" in response. Only when I delete all the records and upload the remaining 2 records, I get the suggester dictionary updated.

Comment: This sounds like perhaps spellchecker ignores the deleted flag. The records are not truly deleted until the segments are merged (e.g. with - not recommended - optimize call, or by hitting the merge threshold) or if all the records in a segment are deleted and the whole segment can be dropped.
Do an experiment. Add other two records, commit. Add your test record, commit. Check it shows up in spelling. Delete just that test record and commit. If it disappears from the spelling, than my assumption is right. Either way, this might be worth taking to the Solr Users mailing list.

Comment: Yes Alexandre, your assumption is right. I added two new records and then one test record. Then I deleted just the test record and it disappeared from the spelling. This is surprising.

Comment: The 'deleted' but not 'merged/purged' records is a deep part of Lucene implementation and does sometimes affect less obvious parts of the system. I have added the comment to the documentation page for this to be reviewed and - if correct - mentioned: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spell+Checking